# environment specific db automation with tfs ci cd

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, winrm, dacpac

I am trying automate db deployment using TFS CI/CD.
MSBuild for building the db which in turn creates dacpac
Winrm for db deployment to an on premise sql server

During build I am passing 
MSBuild Arguments: /t:build /t:publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=db.publish.xml
Contents of db.publish.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>dev_DB</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>db.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=xxx;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True</TargetConnectionString>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My release is currently configured to dev. And QA.. the release is working fine for dev. And it is not working for QA.

One observation is: the SqlPublishProfilePath in build is referring to publish file which is referring to Dev.

I would like to use same dacpack file for dev. And QA. As I have mentioned specific publish file in the release task.

[release configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSSVf.png)

Comment: I try Cece Dong not working changes are not reflecting.

Comment: Could you share the entire log for your release?

Answer (score 0):

In `Publish Profile` argument, usually specify the path to the Publish profile XML file on the ***target machine*** or on a UNC share that is accessible by the machine administrator's credentials.

It seems variable `$(devpublishprofile)` point to a path on your dev machine. You have two option to fix your issue:

1. Put the Publish profile in a UNC share, and specify variable `$(devpublishprofile)` to the UNC share where both Dev and QA can access.
2. Copy the Publish profile from Dev to QA, and locate it in the same path as variable `$(devpublishprofile)` points to.